# Consistent image loading in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with images as rows (cells). I use `EGOImageView` to load images from http url. It loads independently.

**So my question is - is there way to load images consistently from top to bottom. f.e. load second only when first loaded.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a chain of animations on the imageviews' alpha property.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the UITableView in the `connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` method.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
   [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```